# Using SQLite-net in a WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I'm having a bit of a senior moment trying to get SQLite working on a new WPF project. I've recently written a bunch of Windows Store and Phone projects and always used [**the same neat SQLite-net implementation**](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) there, but now I can't seem to do that with my WPF app.

I've added SQLite-net through nuget, but I can't find a version of SQLite3.dll that I can add to the project. When I download it from SQLite.org I get the following error.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? All the tutorials I find tell me to use `System.Data.Sqlite` instead but I don't want to rewrite all my DAL code again

Comment: Not sure what version you're using, but if you pick the right one from here https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki , it has to work. Always did for me...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got it working.

For anyone who's trying to do this - specifically, trying to get **sqlite-NET** to work on WPF, not just SQLite, you need to:

1. download the pre-compiled windows binary of sqlite3.dll from http://www.sqlite.org/download.html
2. copy that dll file into your bin folder
3. go to project properties > build and change the CPU type to x86 (there's no precompiled x64 version at time of writing)

Comment: It can also be downloaded from https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

Comment: When you say 'into your bin folder', do you mean the bin folder of the project, or some other place?  Nuget puts DLLs into a different directory, but that one is not called 'bin'.  Also, how do you add a reference to the dll you just downloaded?

Comment: Attempted this - does not work for me. VS 2017, still has all the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and install an appropriate [System.Data.SQLite](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) setup package from http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki.

This will install the required SQLIte assemblies into your GAC and the design-time components for Visual Studio.

For .NET 4.5.1 (VS 2013) the current link is http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.92.0/sqlite-netFx451-setup-bundle-x86-2013-1.0.92.0.exe

For .NET 4.5 (VS 2012) the current link is http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.92.0/sqlite-netFx45-setup-bundle-x86-2012-1.0.92.0.exe

For .NET 4 (VS 2010) the current link is http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.92.0/sqlite-netFx40-setup-bundle-x86-2010-1.0.92.0.exe

Once you do that you will be able to add required SQLite assembly references in your project.

Here is a screenshot of SQLite assemblies in Add Reference dialog:

[image]

Comment: still not working for me... once I install one of these (in my case .net4) I get that I should be adding a reference, but from where? Where is the dll file?

Comment: It's in the GAC, so don't browse for it, just type in SQLite as soon as you open the add reference dialog.

Comment: Hi Dean. I actually have these added already, but SQLite-net is still throwing the same error. Here's the error: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/568631/sqlite-error-1.png, my references: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/568631/sqlite-error-2.png

Comment: looking back over your answer I strongly suspect this is aimed at a more generic implementation of sqlite rather than specifically implementing the sqlite-net wrapper library as is. Were I to get your implementation to work I'd have to rewrite my code, which is not what I wanted

Comment: Exactly - this in fact does work (adds references to manually write sqlite commands). But, I'm very disinclined to write my own wrapper for things like converting objects back and forth to/from sql results.